# System.Net.WebClient returned not all data from file

Tags: asp.net, .net, webclient

I try `download file via WebClient`, but it returned not all bytes from file. `Original file has 45Kb`, It `download only 8kb` from total file. It happened after I added *user-agent* header.

My code is:

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
     foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> i in filesToInclude)
     {
         System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
         wc.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
         wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
         wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
         string downloadUrl = SPContext.Current.Site.Url + i.Key;    
         AppClass.WriteToLog(string.Format("downloadUrl: {0}", downloadUrl));
         byte[] img = wc.DownloadData(downloadUrl);
         zip.AddEntry(i.Value, img);
      }
      zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
    }
```

Have you any ideas?

**UPDATE:** in the previous version `url` doesn't build correctly. I change my code to:

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
     foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> i in filesToInclude)
     {
          System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
          wc.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
          wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
          wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
          string downloadUrl = SPContext.Current.Site.Url + i.Key;
          Uri uri = new Uri(downloadUrl);
          AppClass.WriteToLog(string.Format("downloadUrl: {0}\nUri.AbsoluteUri: {1}", downloadUrl, uri.AbsoluteUri));
          byte[] img = wc.DownloadData(uri.AbsoluteUri);

          if (!wc.ResponseHeaders.Get(0).Contains("OK"))
          {
               AppClass.WriteToLog("Unable to donwload the file");
          }
          zip.AddEntry(i.Value, img);
      }

      zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
}
```

And now I have another problem. `The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden`

Comment: Can be wrong, but it can be that apache is recognizing that Firefox supports gzipping and sends the file gzipped, try to look with wireshark into the header, if there is gzip there, im right.

Answer (score 1):

Might be an error message or something like that. You're probably not really downloading bytes from the file.
Try to read the result as a string to see if it's not an err message. Or try to get the HTTP response code from the WebClient.

This is a bad way to do it, but you should do some error checking like this:

```
> using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile()) {
>      foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> i in filesToInclude)
>      {
>          System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
>          wc.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
>          wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
>          wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
>          string downloadUrl = SPContext.Current.Site.Url + i.Key;    
>          AppClass.WriteToLog(string.Format("downloadUrl: {0}", downloadUrl));
>          byte[] img = wc.DownloadData(downloadUrl);
>          if (!wc.ResponseHeaders[0].Contains("OK"))
>          {
>            throw new Exception("Unable to donwload the file");
>          }
>          zip.AddEntry(i.Value, img);
>       }
>       zip.Save(Response.OutputStream); 
> }
```

Comment: sorry for waiting but my local network temporary don't work and I couldn't check your example

Comment: Yes. You were right. My `url` wasn't correct. I changed code for build Url and now I gas another problem. Look at the post

Comment: The same url works in your browser ? Then the problem comes either from the credentials either from the headers you're sending. Are you sure you need all of that ?

Comment: `url` works. When I go to this Url browser send auth data in cookie. I looked it in the fiddler.